# Need to create string representation of datetime

Tags: c#

I need to parse a datetime to following string:

```
Nov 30 2012
Dec  1 2012
```

Please note that the date format. For the second example, only one char is there and its padded with a space in starting.

Right now I am doing this:

```
    string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
    string day = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' ');
    string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    string myFormat = month + " " + day + " " + year;
```

Need more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I have edited to show what I am doing right now. Dont be in a hurry to vote down.

Comment: Do you want to parse the date from string or do you want to display date time as string ? Seeing the other answers I am bit confused

Comment: What's the problem with your solution? I don't think it's too inelegant.

Comment: The Title is confusing, question is for actually formatting a `DateTime` and nothing to do with `Parse`.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I have corrected the title. thanks

Comment: All the people who voted it down for because of unclarity: I have made it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I believe it was about generating the output rather than reading it.

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MMM} {0,2:%d} {0:yyyy}", dt));
```

Comment: And this wont work - it will not add additional space, if it needed... And you have extra comma after %d

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get string from DateTime (as in your example), then you can use simple:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Day > 9)
    myFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd YYYY");
else
    myFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM  d YYYY");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with parsing is the variable number of spaces in the string. You may split your string on `" "` (space) with `RemoveEmptyEntries` and then use `string.Join` to create a new string with a single space. Later you can use the format `"MMM d yyyy"` with `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string str = "Dec  1 2012";
string newStr = string.Join(" ", str.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(newStr, "MMM d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT:

Since the question is now edited and it requires a string formatting of the date. Following can be used for formatting.

```
string formattedDate = dt.Day < 10 ? dt.ToString("MMM  d yyyy"): //multiple spaces
                                     dt.ToString("MMM d yyyy"); //single space
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 12, 1);
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:MMM d yyyy}", dt));
```

Edit: Example

If you are looking to have the numbers align then something like

```
//call
MessageBox.Show(GetNewDateString(new DateTime(2012, 11, 30)) + "\n" + GetNewDateString(new DateTime(2012, 12, 1)));

public String GetNewDateString(DateTime dt)
{
   return dt.Day > 9 ? String.Format("{0:MMM d yyyy}", dt) : String.Format("{0:MMM   d yyyy}", dt);
}
```